# How do I subtract every row of a matrix with every row of a second matrix in matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have two matrices A (51 rows X 5100 columns) and B (51rows X 5100 columns) and I want to subtract every row of A with every row of B to obtain another matric C (2601 rows X 5100 columns). How can I have the matrix C?

Answer (score 7):

You can do that by

1. [permuting](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html) the matrices' dimensions to obtain 3D arrays of size (in your example) `51` × `1` × `5100` and `1` × `51` × `5100` respectively;
2. subtracting with [implicit expansion](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/10/24/matlab-arithmetic-expands-in-r2016b/), which gives an array of size `51` × `51` × `5100`;
3. [reshaping](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) to collapse the first two dimensions into one, which gives the final `51*51` × `5100` matrix.

```
A = rand(51, 5100); % example matrix
B = rand(51, 5100); % example matrix, same number of columns
C = reshape(permute(A, [1 3 2]) - permute(B, [3 1 2]), [], size(A, 2));
```

Answer (score 2):

The crux of the problem lies in getting the correct pairs of rows for both matrices. To do this, you could use the `meshgrid()` function to generate a matrix that varies from `1:n` along its rows, and another that varies along its columns (where `n` is the number of rows).

For example:

```
mtx1 = reshape(1:9, 3, 3);
mtx2 = reshape(101:109, 3, 3);
n1 = size(mtx1, 1);
n2 = size(mtx2, 1);

[r1, r2] = meshgrid(1:n1, 1:n2);
```

This gives:

```
r1 =

   1   2   3
   1   2   3
   1   2   3

r2 =

   1   1   1
   2   2   2
   3   3   3
```

Next, flatten both `r1` and `r2`:

```
f1 = r1(:)
f2 = r2(:)
```

Now, we have:

```
f1 =

   1
   1
   1
   2
   2
   2
   3
   3
   3

f2 =

   1
   2
   3
   1
   2
   3
   1
   2
   3
```

We can use `f1` and `f2` as the indices for our pairs of rows:

`mtx1(f1, :)` repeats the first row of `mtx1` three times, then the second row, then the third row

```
mtx1(f1, :)

   1   4   7
   1   4   7
   1   4   7
   2   5   8
   2   5   8
   2   5   8
   3   6   9
   3   6   9
   3   6   9
```

`mtx2(f2, :)` repeats the entire matrix `mtx2` three times

```
mtx2(f2, :)


   101   104   107
   102   105   108
   103   106   109
   101   104   107
   102   105   108
   103   106   109
   101   104   107
   102   105   108
   103   106   109
```

Subtract these two, and you get your pairwise difference of rows:

```
mtx2(f2, :) - mtx1(f1, :)

   100   100   100
   101   101   101
   102   102   102
    99    99    99
   100   100   100
   101   101   101
    98    98    98
    99    99    99
   100   100   100
```

This also works when `mtx1` and `mtx2` have different row counts.